# Android Bitmap snap to grid

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to make images snap to grid when dragging a bitmap?

At the moment I can touch a bitmap and move it smoothly around the screen. I want to be able to make it snap to an invisible grid whilst you are dragging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's what I do in an application I'm just finishing at the moment. When the user is dragging something on the screen, I display a visible snap grid, and the object is snapped to that grid when the dragging has finished. To show a grid, my approach is to use a separate custom `View` that I named `GridOverLayView`. It is overlaid over the entire screen area and it very simply draws a snap grid in its `onDraw()` method. It is made visible only when something is being dragged.

Now, concerning the actual `Activity` in which dragging and dropping is handled, one particular constant I've defined is:

```
static final int SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL = 20;
```

When the object is being dragged around, i.e. when processing `event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` events within my `OnTouchListener`, I perform snapping of the object's location to grid using the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mThingBeingDragged.getLayoutParams();
par.topMargin = Math.round((event.getRawY() - draggedInitialY)   / SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL ) * SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL;  
par.leftMargin = Math.round((event.getRawX() - draggedInitialX)  / SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL ) * SNAP_GRID_INTERVAL;
mThingBeingDragged.setLayoutParams(par);
```

...where `draggedInitialY` and `draggedInitialX` store the initial touch position recorded during the initial `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

A further nice touch is to allow the object being dragged to be moved around without snapping, but have it snap to the grid only in the `.ACTION_UP` when the user lifts their finger. In practice, this feels much nicer to use.

Comment: This is brilliant. Very clear answer. Would rate higher if I could. Thank you for your quick responce. I'll give this a try now.

Answer (score 4):

```
    private PointF touchDown;
    private int gridCellSize = 10;


    private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    touchDown = new PointF(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

                    float yDeff = ((event.getRawY() - touchDown.y)   / gridCellSize ) * gridCellSize;
                    float xDeff = ((event.getRawX() - touchDown.x)  / gridCellSize ) * gridCellSize;

                    if(Math.abs(xDeff) >= gridCellSize)
                    {
                        par.leftMargin += (int)(xDeff / gridCellSize) * gridCellSize;
                        touchDown.x = event.getRawX() - (xDeff % gridCellSize);
                    }

                    if(Math.abs(yDeff) >= gridCellSize)
                    {
                        par.topMargin += (int)(yDeff / gridCellSize) * gridCellSize;
                        touchDown.y = event.getRawY() - (yDeff % gridCellSize);
                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }
                default :
                {

                    break;
                }
            }


            return true;
        }
    };
```