# Drag and Drop in same layout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I've been facing the problem since few days.I want to perform Drag and Drop of Views but not from one layout to other layout but in same Layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409152/android-bitmap-snap-to-grid/9411299#9411299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this here is answer is available may be it is use full

[Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027792/android-drag-and-drop-images-on-the-screen)

And here you see example [Android Drag And drop](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-drag-and-drop-images-in-one.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setX() and setY() on those views,

Comment: I tried but still its now working